# I can't work with javascript file in css and html

Tags: javascript, html, css

My js file

```
var screenwidth=screen.width;
var screenheight=screen.height;


if(screenwidth == 800 && screenheight == 600)
{

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index860.css" />

}

else if(screenwidth == 1024 && screenheight == 768)

{

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index1024.css"  />

}

else if(screenwidth == 1152 && screenheight == 864)

{

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index1152.css"  />

}

else if(screenwidth == 1280 && screenheight == 720)

{

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index1280_720.css"  />

}

else if(screenwidth == 1280 && screenheight == 768)

{

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index1280_768.css"  />

}

else if(screenwidth == 1280 && screenheight == 800)

{

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index1280_800.css"  />

}

else if(screenwidth == 1280 && screenheight == 960)

{

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index1280_960.css"  />

}

else if(screenwidth == 1280 && screenheight == 1024)

{

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Users/bugra/Desktop/project_site/indexl280_1024.css"  />

}


else if(screenwidth == 1360 && screenheight == 768)

{

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index1360.css"  />

}

else if(screenwidth == 1366 && screenheight == 768)

{

    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index1366.css"  />

}

else if(screenwidth == 1600 && screenheight == 900)

{

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index1600_900.css"  />

}


else if(screenwidth == 1600 && screenheight == 1024)

{

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index1600_1024.css" />

}

else if(screenwidth == 1680 && screenheight == 1050)

{

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index1680.css"  />

}

else if(screenwidth == 1920 && screenheight == 1080)

{

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index.css" />




}
```

html file

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="res.js">
</script> 


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


<div id="orta"><center>MERHABA BU SITE IPAD PROJESI ICIN TASARLANDI <p> PROJE : LEZZET DUNYASI<p> BURAK KURAL <p> BUĞRA SÖNMEZ <p> GÜRCAN DİNLER <p> BÜKE YOLAÇAN</></div>


</body>
</html>
```

one of my css

```
html{
       height: 98%;

    }


body {
    background-color:#000;
    background-image:url(rsz_ipad-template-horiz.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50% 50%;
     }



#orta {

       background-color:#CFF;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       height:431px;
       width:698px;
       margin-left:602px;
       margin-top:262px;
       font-size:22px;
       font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
       font-style:oblique;

      }


}
```

I try to run this html code on my local computer and all files are in the same folder.

When i click html file , ı just see the result of code which is written  between   .

Firstly i wrote internal js than use external maybe that was the reason but nothing changed.

For another solution , tried to

```
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index860.css" />');
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index860.css" />
```

again nothing changed.

I looked at the code but i didn't see any syntax error in it. I'm new at js so maybe i miss sometihng but i cant find it.

Comment: Use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to link to code.

Comment: Can you show the actual code instead of linking to hosted files?  It would be best to strip out all unnecessary code to reproduce the problem with as little as possible.  (Most times you'll find that this process results in discovering the answer.)

Comment: This question is far _far_ to broad. StackOverflow isn't here to fix entire pages for you. Have you tried anything yourself before asking here?

Comment: Please put down all details. What do you mean by 'running' the HTML file? Where are you hosting them? How do you know that the JS is not running? It is not possible to tell you the reason for your problem with the information that you have provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You messed up javascript with html. You can't put markup in JS file. If you wan't print something to page you should use `document.writeln('...')`. Example:

```
if(screenwidth == 800 && screenheight == 600) {
    document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\bugra\Desktop\project_site\index860.css" />');
}
```

Also href in link tag is not right. It should be url. If you want link file from local disk you should write it as `file:///C:/Users/bugra/Desktop/project_site/index860.css`.

Comment: +1 for actually going to the effort to download the files from Mediafire and fix the OP's problem. I think "RTFM" would be appropriate here :-P